# How to swich variants with Homebrew?

Tags: mpi, homebrew, hdf5

Let's say I install `hdf5` as:

```
$brew install hdf5 --build-from-source --with-mpi
```

Then I want to build `hdf5` without `open-mpi` as:

```
$brew install hdf5 --build-from-source
```

How should I install and switch between both variants?

Should I write a different formula for `hdf5-parallel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t have multiple variants of the same formula with the same version installed at the same time. You need to either create another formula or try to copy the HDF5 directory somewhere else before rebuilding it but it’s hacky and might not work correctly.

Comment: I guess I can simply change the name of the directory and reinstall. Is there any clean and safe way of doing this without messing everything up?

Comment: You can do something like `brew unlink hdf5 && mv /usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.16 ~/my_hdf5 && brew install hdf5 --build-from-source`. Note that you can also use `-s` as an alias of `--build-from-source`.

Comment: Thanks good idea.  I did `brew unlink hdf5 && /usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.16_1 /usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.8.16_1_par && brew install hdf5 -s`. Now I can use `brew switch`

Comment: as you said it's hacky. Changing moving directories works with `hdf5` but not with `open-mpi`. It required some time and pain to realize this.